# MS Access SQL On Update/On Delete

Tags: sql, ms-access, cascade, onupdate

I am practicing SQL in MS Access for my test. Currently trying to create constraints on a table.

```
CREATE TABLE Container (
Nr int NOT NULL,
Soort varchar(255),
Aanschaf double NOT NULL,
Huurprijs double NOT NULL,
Verhuurder varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Nr),
CONSTRAINT fk_verh FOREIGN KEY (Verhuurder)
REFERENCES Verhuurbedrijf
ON UPDATE cascade
ON DELETE cascade
);
```

I get a syntax error on the ON UPDATE cascade. UPDATE turns black. Not sure what is wrong here?

I used this documentation as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx

Keep in mind I have to learn how to do it programmatically through SQL.

Comment: Does table.field  `verhurrbedrijf.verhuurder` exist as a primary key? (what does the create table for Verhuurbedrijf look like?)  if the table and key don't exist, that's the problem.  that table has to be created 1st.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Verhuurbedrijf (
Naam varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Plaats varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Naam)
); Thats my code for the table Verhuurbedrijf. Verhuurder is the field in the table container. If I leave out the on update and on delete, the table will be created.

Comment: To start with, you are missing the primary key column referenced by Verhuurder column.

Comment: One can not create a  foreign key to a non key field.  If naam is the primary key, you should be referencing naam instead of verhuurder.  Does `CONSTRAINT fk_verh FOREIGN KEY (naam)
REFERENCES Verhuurbedrijf
ON UPDATE cascade
ON DELETE cascade` work instead? but I'm not sure that achieves the same desired result.

Comment: I thought it automatically refers to the primary key field in the table Verhuurbedrijf? Am I allowed to share links to other websites here? http://i.imgur.com/iCd3CUO.png I am trying to create these four tables where the italic column names are foreign keys.

Comment: xQbert, changing the constraint in the way you mentioned still gives me the syntaxis error on the UPDATE keyword.